# Random number and database check

Tags: asp-classic

I'm having some issues generating a unique ID, and also checking to make sure that the generated ID is not already in the database. I wrote two simple functions, but every time they run, I get an out of memory error.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is my code:

```
uniqueID = getID()

function getID()
Dim id : id = getUniqueID 'simple random number generator
    if checkForID(id) = 0 then
        return id
    else
        id = getID()
    end if
end function

function checkForID(id)
    SQL="SELECT * FROM userOrderDxTest WHERE orderID =" & id
    set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.Open SQL,DB,adOpenStatic
    if not rs.EOF then
        checkForID = 1   'ID already exists
        rs.close
        set rs = nothing
    else
        checkForID = 1    'ID doesn't exist
    rs.CLOSE
    end if
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you always set checkForID to 1. It should be:

```
if not rs.EOF then
    checkForID = 1   'ID already exists
    rs.close
    set rs = nothing
else
    checkForID = 0    'ID doesn't exist
```